# How to fix white level Error page in springboot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to run a small spring boot project,but here i am getting white level Error page.How to resolve this issue?

```
SpringBootAnnotationApplication.java
=====================================
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.controller"})
public class SpringBootAnnotationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAnnotationApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

## Controller Class

```
BootController.java
===================

@Controller
public class BootController {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean mybean;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String theHandler() {

        return mybean.getMessage();
    }
}

MyBean.java
===========
@Component
public class MyBean {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "message from my bean class";
    }
}
```

Where i am going Wrong can anyone please suggest me?

Comment: What is a "white level Error page" ? What do you *want* to happen? If you want to show the message in an HTML page - you need to create an HTML page and provide the message to it. If you want to just output the message in a rest service - you need the `@RestController` annotation instead of the `@Controller` annotation (or annotate the method with `@ResponseBody`)

Comment: In the above code I missed @ResponseBody Annotation.